# Running gulp tasks on CruiseControl.NET

Tags: node.js, gulp, cruisecontrol.net

Does anyone have any experience of running gulp on CruiseControl? 
We have some troubles to automate the process through xml config file. Tasks can be launched through CommandPrompt manually on local and virtual machines, but when launched from CruiseControl there is an error:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.BuilderException: Unable to execute: gulp TaskName

System.IO.IOException: Unable to execute file [D:\CC.NET\VSS\%CorrectPathName%\gulp]. The file may not exist or may not be executable.
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE** 
After trying out what *Simon Laing* has suggested, started to get another error:

```
  <buildresults>
  <message level="Error">module.js:327</message>
  <message level="Error">    throw err;</message>
  <message level="Error">    ^</message>
  <message level="Error">Error: Cannot find module 'D:\CC.NET\VSS\Path\to\the\project\gulp'</message>
  <message level="Error">    at Function.Module._resolveFilename  (module.js:325:15)</message>
  <message level="Error">    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25) </message>
  <message level="Error">    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10) </message>
  <message level="Error">    at startup (node.js:139:18)</message>
  <message level="Error">    at node.js:968:3</message>
  </buildresults>
  </build>
  </cruisecontrol>
```

The PATH was set to: %APPDATA%\npm, gulp was installed through

```
npm install gulp -g
```

and

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

It seems to me config launches node that is searching for gulp in a wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp is executed normally from the command line via the gulp-cli, which removes the need to execute `node` with the `gulp` argument.

To resolve your issue you need to tell cruise control which executable (node.exe) to run with which tool and it's arguments.

In your case it should be:

- Filename: `Path\to\node.exe`
- Arguments: `gulp <any-other-switches>`

**Alternative solution**, get cmd to execute node for you:

- Filename: `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe`
- Arguments: `/c gulp <any-other-switches>`

`cmd` can then read the *path* and execute note as `gulp-cli` would control if you were invoking it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now getting another error: 
`<message level="Error">Error: Cannot find module 'D:\path\to\gulp'</message>
  <message level="Error">    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)</message>
  <message level="Error">    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)</message>
  <message level="Error">    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)</message>
  <message level="Error">    at startup (node.js:139:18)</message`

Any ideas about this one?

Comment: it is quite obvious that cruise control doesn't see the path to the gulp file. I still can't figure out how it can be changed.

Comment: Has gulp been installed globally or per user?

Comment: You mean if it is installed for all users? Installed it as 'gulp -g' and 'gulp --save-dev'. But global installation isn't generally going for  %AllUsers%, by default it's going to current user's folder. And in this case it was installed as Cruise Control user. 
You think this could be the issue?

Comment: I've edited my answer with an alternative which I've proven to work

Comment: I was already trying the same, but seems like the gulp isn't running/doing what it should. At least the build is successful. 
Is there any way I can check what is going on when that task is executed?

Comment: I've added '<baseDirectory>' with own project, where 'gulpfile.js', after that everything started to run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, I know but, even after trying the approach in the accepted answer above I continued to have the same issue.

In my case, I was using "au build" to build an aurelia app, which needs to find and run node.  No matter how much I tried, I just could NOT get CCNet to see the path, so I added an "Environment" block to the task, and copied my system path directory into it.

Once I did that, everything was happy again.

For reference, this is what the exec task in my CCNet.config file now looks like.

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">

<project name="blahproject">


    <sourcecontrol type="git">
    ...
    </sourcecontrol>

    <triggers>
    ...
    </triggers>

    <tasks>

        <exec>
            <executable>C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe</executable>
            <baseDirectory>C:\myproject\working\folder</baseDirectory>
            <buildArgs>/c au build</buildArgs>
            <buildTimeoutSeconds>60</buildTimeoutSeconds>
            <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
          <environment>
            <variable>
                <name>path</name>
                <value>C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\</value>
            </variable>
        </environment>
        </exec>

    <msbuild>
      ...
    </msbuild>

  </tasks>

</project>

</cruisecontrol>
```

As you can see, the environment sets the path so that all my tooling can be found, while using the base directory tag to effectively set the working directory where your project files are.